# breakpoint is hitting twice in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, breakpoints

I have this problem with the break point I have set.I have created a small application in android and I want to display the result in one activity , but the thing is the result is getting displayed as null value always ,I have put a break point to find the bug and  I have found the issue here as it is hitting the break point twice , during the first time it is working on debugging but it again hitting the break point i don't know why? then I am getting a null value, I know I have done some mistake somewhere , So please i need some help to solve the issue.

giving my java class below

```
      public class ShowScoreActivity extends Activity {
      Bundle getBundle;
  int score;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.score_form);
    TextView txtScore;
    txtScore=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtScore);


**breakpoint here -->** Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    {
    score=extras.getInt("finalScore");
    txtScore.setText(txtScore.getText().toString()+ " "+ score);
    }



    Button btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(ShowScoreActivity.this);         
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.thank_you_dialog);   
            dialog.setTitle("Quiz over !");         
            dialog.show();
            Button btnOk=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnThanks);
            btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent in = new 
                      Intent(ShowScoreActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });

        }
             });

               }

                      }
```

Main activity java classs

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
DbCreation dbcr;
Button btnStart;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.idHomBtn);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
            Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowQuizActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: what is variable is `null`?

Comment: Could you edit your post to show which line you have set your break point on?

Comment: And if you could indent it properly, it would help for sure.

Comment: Please post the code of the MainActivity onCreate() method as well and the android manifest file

Comment: Most likely you are creating the Activity twice, so the code is run twice.

Comment: I have edited the code with break point. And I tried giving different intents too,but of no use.

Comment: In your MainActivity.class you call ShowQuizActivity.class, but the issue is in ShowScoreActivity.class?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a [known Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339984). Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any workaround for the time being :(